# Which is the best term to use for a Face-to-Face interview

Tags: terminology

We are a BPO company and does lot of UK and US IT recruiting. We normally have two types of interviews - the first is telephonic and second is at client's office. Our recruiters use the term "Face-to-Face" interview and "Inperson" interview to indicate the latter type of interview.

We are now trying to prepare a uniform template for interview invitations and I would like to know the best term to indicate the second type of interview. Please also suggest if there are any other standard terms which can be used for the same purpose.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is on topic on ELU.

Comment: Face to face interview is best suited for this type of interviews. Also, unless otherwise mentioned explicitly that the interview is telephonic, this one is considered by default.

Comment: btw: what is BPO?   and why say "We are... and does"?

Comment: I would use "in-person".  "Face-to-face" could be taken to mean using Skype, etc, while "in-person" is clear and unambiguous.

Comment: F2F (Face-to-Face) is the most widely understood and unambiguous term today, invented by necessity after telephonic interviews/ skype video interactions became popular. In order to be brief and yet very clear, it is almost necessary to use the term F2F.

Comment: @HotLicks Using skype etc., is not considered "in-person," the later term meaning the physical presence of the persons at the same place.

Comment: @Kris - That's what I said.  "Face-to-face" could be interpreted to include Skype, while "in-person" is not likely to be interpreted that way.

Comment: @HotLicks However, in reality, F2F does not include skype interaction. It excludes *every* thing other than physical presence.

Comment: @Kris - Only by convention.  It's not clear to person who is not in "the business".  (In fact, what "F2F" even stands for is not clear.)

Comment: @HotLicks http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/face-to-face?q=face+to+face

Answer (score 2):

**In-person**

> in one's own bodily presence; personally: *Applicants are requested to apply in person.*

**Face-to-face**

> 1. with the fronts or faces toward each other, especially when close together.
> 2. involving close contact or direct opposition: *a face-to-face confrontation of adversaries.*

(Definitions and examples from Dictionary.com.)

I would recommend *in-person* over *face-to-face*, only because there is that slight hint of confrontation and tension associated with face-to-face, which I don't think you want in your application.

Answer (score 1):

*Face-to-face interview* is fine. I can't think of a better, clearer, or more common phrase.

I would say that *telephone interview* is better than *telephonic interview* though. *Telephonic* does not sound natural - although I understand exactly what it means, it sounds like something a non-native would say.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe an "Interpersonal" interview? :)

Comment: Why would a telephonic interview not be "interpersonal"?